# django angular anonymous user

Tags: angularjs, django, angular-http, django-angular

I am sending an $http get request from my angular client to my Django backend, where (request.user) gives me *Anonymous*. Because of this I can do anything on server side.

I am using *django-rest-auth* on django side and *angular-django-registration-auth* on client side to do authentication. Authentication itself is successful- I can login and retrieve username, email id on client side sent from server.

My request looks like following:

```
 var url = "http://localhost:8000/api/exercises/get_exercise/" + exerciseType + "/";

   $http({
            url: url,
            method: 'GET',
            headers: {'X-CSRFToken': $cookies['csrftoken']}
        })

          .success(function(response){

            console.log(response);

           });
      })
```

In my app config I have following line added:

```
$httpProvider.defaults.withCredentials = this.use_session;
```

The request headers as seen from my chrome browser console are as follows:

```
Accept:application/json, text/plain, */*
Accept-Encoding:gzip, deflate, sdch
Accept-Language:de-DE,de;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.6,en;q=0.4,en-GB;q=0.2
Authorization:Token eb979cb6f179dd2d9056023685e2d02e4e65a58e
Connection:keep-alive
Host:localhost:8000
Origin:http://localhost:8100
Referer:http://localhost:8100/
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/49.0.2623.87 Safari/537.36
```

If I hit the same url from my django api endpoint directly at 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/exercises/get_exercise/2/' where my django server is running it is successful and request headers are as follows:

```
Accept:text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Encoding:gzip, deflate, sdch
Accept-Language:de-DE,de;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.6,en;q=0.4,en-GB;q=0.2
Cache-Control:max-age=0
Connection:keep-alive
Cookie:csrftoken=GDco30gJ9vki6LDtqJSuQh9hGB0aXp84;     sessionid=94xfwx9zvr4pgd1wx9r0nemjwmy3mowi
Host:127.0.0.1:8000
Upgrade-Insecure-Requests:1
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/49.0.2623.87 Safari/537.36
```

**The difference I see is that the successful request sends cookies and session info, where as it is missing from the request sent from my angular app.**

What is the reason and the workaround?

My Django settings.py has following:

```
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES': (
    'rest_framework.authentication.BasicAuthentication',
    'rest_framework.authentication.SessionAuthentication',
    'rest_framework.authentication.TokenAuthentication',
),
'DEFAULT_PERMISSION_CLASSES': (
    'rest_framework.permissions.IsAuthenticated',
),

}
```

My django view looks like following:

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from rest_framework.authentication import TokenAuthentication,     SessionAuthentication, BasicAuthentication
from rest_framework.permissions import IsAuthenticated
from rest_framework.response import Response
from rest_framework.views import APIView
from rest_framework.decorators import api_view
from rest_framework.decorators import authentication_classes
from rest_framework.decorators import permission_classes 

class JSONResponse(HttpResponse):
authentication_classes = (SessionAuthentication, BasicAuthentication)
permission_classes = (IsAuthenticated,)
"""
An HttpResponse that renders its content into JSON.
"""
def __init__(self, data, **kwargs):
    content = JSONRenderer().render(data)
    kwargs['content_type'] = 'application/json'
    super(JSONResponse, self).__init__(content, **kwargs)

#view to get a specific exercise for a particular user
def get_single_exercise_for_user_id(request, exerciseId):

  results = Exercise_state_ui_model.fetch_exercises(request.user.id, exerciseId)

  serializer = ExerciseStateSerializer(results, many=True)
  return JSONResponse(serializer.data)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Authorization:Token eb979cb6f179dd2d9056023685e2d02e4e65a58e
```

Makes me think you need to enable token authentication on that view.

```
#view to get a specific exercise for a particular user
@api_view(('GET',))
def get_single_exercise_for_user_id(request, exerciseId):

     results = Exercise_state_ui_model.fetch_exercises(request.user.id, exerciseId)

     serializer = ExerciseStateSerializer(results, many=True)
     return Response(serializer.data)
```

Comment: I have updated my question with snippets from my settings.py and views.py. Can you take a look if there is something missing?

Comment: You need to decorate that view. Also take out that JSONresponse, let rest_framework decide the content it returns based on what the client asks for.

Comment: Awesome! your solution worked!! I wasted my two days searching for all possible reasons! Thanks a lot!